# Recursive sql query for folding rows into each other

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, rows

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time now but i am sure there is a way to do it. I have a table with records of stays at our facilities. Each row has a clientID, rowID, a start date, an end date, a type and the rowID of the previous stay.

Something like this:

| Client id | stayId | previous_stay | start_date | end_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | null | 1-1-2010 | 20-6-2010 | A |
| 1 | 105 | 101 | 1-7-2010 | 30-12-2020 | B |
| 1 | 108. | null | 8-10-2012 | 10-12-2012 | B |

and i want to write a query  to get me a result like this for every client we have

| Client id | stayId | first_stay | start_date | end_date | types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 105 | 101 | 1-1-2010 | 30-12-2010 | 2 |
| 1 | 108 | null | 8-10-2012 | 10-12-2012 | 1 |

I think the best way to do this is a recursive sql query but i dont really know how to do that, can anyone help me?
I am working with oracle sql

Comment: Is 2010 a typo in the end_date in the desired output? Other than that - what is "recursive" or "hierarchical" here? Without further explanation, it seems that all you need is a simple aggregation - as Gordon Linoff has demonstrated in his answer already.

Comment: i edited the question to be more precise, i need to do a recursion on the previous stay column

Comment: The edited output doesn't make sense. For stayid = 108, why is first_stay null? The first stay in that sequence is 108, not null (at least, judging by what you show as "first stay" for the first pair of stays). Also, you still have a discrepancy between 2020 in inputs and 2010 in the output. Did you mean 2010 in the input, end_date, second row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task correctly, this can be done with a `connect by` query (hierarchical query) followed by aggregation, which can be done in the same `select` statement. Like this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
with
  sample_data (clientid, stayid, previous_stay, start_date, end_date, type_) as (
    select 1, 101, null, to_date('1-1-2010') , to_date('20-6-2010') , 'A' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 105, 101 , to_date('1-7-2010') , to_date('30-12-2020'), 'B' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 108, null, to_date('8-10-2012'), to_date('10-12-2012'), 'B' from dual
  )
select  clientid, 
        min(case connect_by_isleaf when 1 then stayid end) as stayid,
        min(case level             when 1 then stayid end) as first_stay,
        min(start_date) as first_start_date,
        max(end_date)   as last_end_date,
        count(distinct type_) as distinct_types
from    sample_data
start   with previous_stay is null
connect by prior stayid = previous_stay and prior clientid = clientid
group   by clientid, connect_by_root(stayid)
;

CLIENTID STAYID FIRST_STAY FIRST_START_DATE LAST_END_DATE DISTINCT_TYPES
-------- ------ ---------- ----------       ------------- --------------
       1    105        101 01-01-2010       30-12-2020                 2
       1    108        108 08-10-2012       10-12-2012                 1
```

The output is different from yours in two places: the last end date for STAYID 105 is in year 2020, not 2010 as you show, because the input shows 2020. (Probably a typo either in your sample input or in your sample output). And, for STAYID 108, the first stayid is 108, not NULL as you show in your output; indeed, NULL is not the STAYID of any stay in your inputs, so it doesn't make sense to appear as "first stay" in the output.

Comment: This works! amazing, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select clientid, max(stayid), min(stayid), min(startdate), max(enddate),
       count(distinct type)
from t
group by clientid;
```

Comment: no, maybe i should have explained a bit better, but a client can have multiple different stays that do not follow each other

Comment: i updated the question to be more precise